# saving only doubledigit numbers into my attribute

Tags: java

I got a task for a Season Object which can only save doubledigit integer numbers as the season number.

How can I initialize the value properly so it will only store doubledigit numbers?
I'm not allowed to use methods or my constructor for that.

the only possible solution I found (even though it would be dumb) is to use an enum from 1 to 99.

Is this really the solution? I'm also not allowed to use API classes for that.

Edit:

```
public class Season {
    String name;
    Series series;
    int seasonNumber;

    public Season () {  }

}
```

I didn't post the code on purpose cause it isn't anything that will help

Edit2: (Tl;Dr of the Task)

The Task is to create a Series, Season and Episode Object. Series and Episode aren't of interest as for this question. The Season Object is defined as you can see in the code above.
The overall conditions are as following:
- primitive datatypes, String, enum are allowed and every class I wrote myself.
- no API classes are allowed.
- methods aren't needed.
- constructor isn't allowed to modify my number with regEx or anything like that

Comment: Are you sure you're not allowed to use *any* form of method to do this? Or do you mean methods not created by yourself?

Comment: Show us the code you have done so far. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in the task it is said that I'm only allowed to use the primitive datatypes, enums, Strings but not any API class. It also says that methods aren't needed at all in my task and the constructor doesn't use the seasonnumber for this test purpose

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What is "Season Object"? In what sense do you have a "task"? What "value" do you initialize? You only have a "Java" tag, but Java does not explain any of these terms. If they are all your own code, please show your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Najinhin.  What does your code look like?  Can you post what you've written so far?  It will give us a better idea, and we can then help you.

Comment: In your definition of a double digit, do you include numbers like 01, 02, etc.? Or just the numbers 10-99 (both inclusive)?

Comment: When you create a Season object, how do you set the season number?  Unless the variable is public, then it'll be tricky, but if it is tricky then surely you can do: season = 01; or are you being fed the information in a specific format?

Comment: What do you want to get if the number below 10? RuntimeException?

Comment: @MartinMJ 01-99
I'm not getting any numbers in right now. I just have to make sure that my attribute CAN'T take any other number than 01-99 but without modifying my constructor in any way for that. so my only thought would be the enum.

Comment: @Najinjin Is it possible for us to see the assignment? Because this seems awfully weird.

Comment: @MartinMJ it is in german so I don't know if it would help. but I'm going to summarize it as good as possible in my question

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I can come up with:

```
public Season(int seasonNumber) {
    if (seasonNumber < 1 || seasonNumber > 99) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value between 1 and 99 (both inclusive) required. Found + " seasonNumber);
    }
    this.seasonNumber = seasonNumber;
}
```

I am not using a method, because the logic is all in the constructor. Though I suspect the person who gave you this hasn't got his point across with the assignment texts.

If you want the season number returned as 01, 02, etc., you could create a method that returns a String, instead of an int:

```
public String getSeasonNumber() {
    if (seasonNumber < 10) {
        return "0" + seasonNumber;
    } else {
        return seasonNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the problem. I also thought about this but it clearly says the constructor only takes a seriesObject and the name not the number.

Comment: Where does it say this? Also, is what you just added to your original question the complete assignment text? If so, it says nothing about double digits.

Comment: later on in the task it clearly says: the season constructor gets a series Object and the name, and will be set to the corresponding attributes. the other attributes won't be used. (kinda a 1:1 translation)

Comment: Are you sure the constructor has no parameters?

Comment: it has. the series Object and the seasonName but not a number. Edit: that's why I'm asking this question. I'm not that bad with Java. I'm helping a friend with this task here but can't find the answer myself because the task is limiting him so much. The only possibilty would be an Enum from 1 - 99 which came to my mind

Comment: Then you should edit your original question to reflect that. How are you supposed to know what the season number is?